# Dynamics 365 Finance and Operations SalesOrderLineEntity validation extension

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-365-operations

I'm still fairly new to x++ development.  I'm trying to add some validation to the SalesOrderLineEntity to stop users importing qty's that are not divisible by multiple qty.

This is how far I've gotten, I can't workout how to write in x++ (if ordered qty not divisible by multiple qty (i.e. not whole number)) then throw an error.

```
[ExtensionOf(tableStr(SalesOrderLineEntity))]
final class SalesOrderLineEntity_Extension
{
boolean validateWrite()
{
InventItemSalesSetup inventItemSalesSetup;
SalesLine salesLine;

SalesTable salesTable = SalesTable::find(this.SalesOrderNumber);

select firstonly * from salesLine where salesLine.salesid == salesTable.SalesId
join inventItemSalesSetup where inventItemSalesSetup.ItemId == salesLine.ItemId;

if (this.RecId)
{
if (salesLine.QtyOrdered < inventItemSalesSetup.MultipleQty)
{
return checkFailed
("qty ordered less than multiple qty");
}
if (isInteger(salesLine.QtyOrdered / inventItemSalesSetup.MultipleQty))
{
return checkFailed
("qty ordered not divisible by multiple qty");
}
}

next validateWrite();

if (!salesTable.checkUpdate(true, true, true))
{
return false;
}

boolean ret;

//ret = super();

return ret;

}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using integers, you need to use the modulo operation (`mod`) in AX. Make sure to check that you're not dividing by zero (the world could end) and you probably want to check that a non-zero quantity was actually entered.

```
if(salesLine.QtyOrdered && inventItemSalesSetup.MultipleQty && (salesLine.QtyOrdered mod inventItemSalesSetup.MultipleQty != 0)
{
    return checkFailed("qty ordered not divisible by multiple qty");
}
```

If you are using reals, then you want to do some basic integer math.

```
real            qtyOrdered;
real            multipleQty;
int             result;

qtyOrdered  = 321.0; // 321 / 10.7 = 30 exactly
multipleQty = 10.7;
result      = qtyOrdered / multipleQty; // This will store the integer and drop any decimals

// If the result multipled by the original multiple is equal to the original value, then you're good
if (result * multipleQty == qtyOrdered)
{
    info("All good!");
}
else
{
    info("Bad!");
}
```

There *may* be a standard AX function that does what you want, but it's so basic I just do the math myself.

Answer (score 0):

Please see finished code, I believe this is now doing what I want.  Thanks for the help. Any suggestions/efficiencies/improvements to this would be greatly appreciated!

```
[ExtensionOf(dataentityviewstr(SalesOrderLineEntity))]
final class SalesOrderLineEntity_Extension
{
    boolean validateWrite()
    {
        InventItemSalesSetup    inventItemSalesSetup;
        SalesLine               salesLine;
    select firstonly * from salesLine where salesLine.Salesid == this.SalesOrderNumber
        && salesLine.ItemId == this.ItemNumber
        join inventItemSalesSetup where inventItemSalesSetup.ItemId == this.ItemNumber;

    boolean ret = next validateWrite();

    if (ret)
    {
        if (ret && this.OrderedSalesQuantity < inventItemSalesSetup.MultipleQty)
        {
            ret = checkFailed ("qty ordered less than multiple qty");
        }
        if (ret && this.OrderedSalesQuantity mod inventItemSalesSetup.MultipleQty != 0)
        {
            ret = checkFailed ("qty ordered not divisible by multiple qty");
        }
    }

    return ret;

}
```

}